# Why isn't the image in my image control clear?

Tags: wpf, bitmapimage

```
BitmapImage B = new BitmapImage();
B.BeginInit();
B.StreamSource = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("WpfApplication26.Back1.png");
B.EndInit();
image1.Source = B;
```

The size of the image (Back1.png) is 32*32, and I set the size of my image control to 32*32 and set the property "Scale" to "None".

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
```

on the image control in xaml or

```
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(image1, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor)
```

in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` on the image control.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to clear the image, meaning, turning it to blank, just set the source to "null"

```
image1.Source = null;
```

This does not require a BitmapImage.

Sorry for the late reply...